# Regex that distinguishes // (comment) from / (division) and vice versa

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to build a language syntax file for Vim and I'm stuck in a part.

The language uses `//` for comments and `/` for the division operator.

I tried to use the following regex definitions:

```
syn match pslComment "\v//.*$"
syn match pslOperator "\v\/"
```

But my comments (`//`) are always matched as a division operator (`/`).

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: does your language assign special meaning to the slash in regex? ie do slashes need to be escaped?

Comment: No, slashes are not used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments:

```
//
```

Division:

```
[^/]/[^/]
```